# Apache runs as which user, group under OS X 10.6?

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, permissions

Anyone know the default user/group for Apache under OS X (10.6)? I'd like to set permissions correctly. Already enabled Web Sharing, etc.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Apache user and group are **_www** and **_www**.

Answer (score 19):

Turns out the answer is in /etc/apache2/original/httpd.conf:

```
User _www
Group _www
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ id _www
uid=70(_www) gid=70(_www) groups=70(_www),404(com.apple.sharepoint.group.3),402(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),61(localaccounts),12(everyone),403(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Default to user **`_www`** and group **`_www`**.

### Check

You can check by running this command:

```sh
$ sudo apachectl -D DUMP_RUN_CFG

ServerRoot: "/usr/local/opt/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/usr/local/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/usr/local/var/log/httpd/error_log"
Mutex default: dir="/usr/local/var/run/httpd/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/usr/local/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="_www" id=70
Group: name="_www" id=70
```

### Check / Change

Also, to check and/or change, you can go to your **`httpd.conf`** file and look for the following part:

```sh
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User _www
Group _www
```

If you don't know where is Apache's `httpd.conf` file:

```sh
# Run this command to find where is httpd.conf 
# (look for this line `SERVER_CONFIG_FILE`, the last line here)
$ httpd -V

Server version: Apache/2.4.33 (Unix)
Server built:   Apr  3 2018 17:54:07
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:76
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_FLOCK_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf" <<< Where httpd.conf is
```

Comment: Fyi I noticed that sudo apachectl restart does not reflect a change to the user in the config, stop start needed.